# Why was this question about FTL engines closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions, closed-questions

Why was the following question closed?

[What are the different types and classes of FTL engines?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/705/what-are-the-different-types-and-classes-of-ftl-engines)

> closed as not a real question by Zypher♦ 13 hours ago
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

I see Zypher seems to be arbitarily closing questions, which seems to be malicious and vexing for what is (if you read it) a NON-subjective question.

A list of FTL drives in science fiction? Anybody who has read for more than a couple of years will be able to provide an answer.

You must understand that this Q & A site is more than a simple Q & A site. It's more a discussion, and as lots of folk don't understand what SF is, you need to allow the question to sit for some time so that people can understand what's being asked.

Also coming from software engineering, I know what subjective is, have used Stack Overflow for donkeys, and know how to avoid it.

This is a beta site, it's fragile, and you're going to drive away your core folk, who are passionate about your site, the folk who will make it a success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Zypher closing too many questions arbitrarily?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137/is-zypher-closing-too-many-questions-arbitrarily)

Comment: I explained why in this answer: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137/is-zypher-closing-too-many-questions-arbitrarily/152#152

Comment: @Zypher, that doesn't address the issue at hand. I don't you have an understanding of what subjective is.

Comment: I didn't close it as subjective.

Comment: @Zypher, why was it closed.

Answer (score 4):

I've just added a comment to this question, which I'll quote here:

> For those casting reopen votes and flagging this question:  please read [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), specifically the part about "going first":  *your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers*.

Comment: I understand your sentiment, and that you have certain rules to follow. But SF is not stack overflow, or the maths site, where you have a single physical answer for question. How do you apply this method? Only 1 or 2 ways of doin it. You'll see a lot of answers on Stack Over are short. But for this science, we dealing with fictional books, which have sometimes have many different intepretations of whats been written, so answers for the more complex questions are never going to be simple.

Answer (score -1):

I think part of the problem is that they're not getting how different topics lend themselves to slightly different interpretations of the same rules.

Comment: Are you saying that this needs to be more like a forum and less of a useful place that adheres to a standard and high quality?